# clipping out object from a video/movie/gif

Tags: adobe

How do I clip out a object from a video/gif/movie and use it elsewhere, where it still moves? I have Adobe PS CS6, After Effects CC 2015 and Sony Vegas Pro 13.

Here is an [example](https://i.imgur.com/kbAkW0D.gifv) of what I mean.

Comment: Welcome to Video Production. There are various ways to do what you want to do. To help us answer give us some more detail about the footage - a screenshot or video link would be the most useful and will enable us to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Video production. To do this using After effects use the mask tool to draw around the object, you have to do this at each frame of the footage. Then bring in the footage you want the object to be in. (make sure you put it below the object layer) then you can move the object to any part of the footage you want. Or you can view this playlist of making tutorials to know more about masking; https://m.youtube.com/user/SurfacedStudio/search?itct=CAUQuy8iEwi2sOr165HOAhVMIBwKHZZMB44%3D&query=Mask